# DVD Player error 47

Tags: error, optical-drive, dvd, dvd-player

I am unable to eject a disk from Apple DVD player. It shows "Error ~47" when I click on Eject button. Changed some DVD Player settings, such as cleared "Start playing disk" so that no files would be open when I connect the DVD player, but that did't help.

Searched Apple website; it has posts by other users about "Error ~47" in various settings, and comments about that being a file error, but no indication on how to fix that.

My system: MacBook Pro, Yosemite 10.10.3.

Please advise how to remove the DVD from the DVD player.

Answer (score 1):

Got it: another user account from the same Mac had a file open on that DVD.